# find list of similar keys in dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

I have a dictionary with almost similar keys and other keys as well. I need to extract all the values with almost similar keys.
Example:

```
example_dictionary = {'ab1':'1', 'ab2':'2','ab3':'3', 'cd1':'4', 'cd2':'5', 'cd3':'6', 'ef1':'7', 'sdsf':'8', 'ad':'9', 'ef2':'10', 'ef3':'11'}  
keymatch = ['ab','cd','ef']
```

Here we have a mapping of `cd1` with `ef1, cd2` with `ef2, cd3` with `ef3`.

Result I need is the value of all `ab1, ab2, ab3, cd1, cd2, cd3, ef1, ef2, ef3.`

I tried:

```
abList = [val for key, val in example_dictionary.items() if keymatch[0] in key]
```

This gives me all values of `ab1, ab2, ab3`

I tried:

```
result = [val for key, val in example_dictionary.items() for item in keymatch if item in key]
```

This gives me all values of `ab1, ab2, ab3, cd1, cd2, cd3, ef1, ef2, ef3`
But the problem with second approach is I'm not able to map `cd1` with `ef1`.

Can somebody provide a better approach?

Answer (score 0):

IIUC you want to have a dict where 'similar keys' are merged. You can do so by combining a dictionary comprehension with a list comprehension.

```
{km: [v for k, v in example_dictionary.items() if km in k] for km in keymatch}

{'ab': ['1', '2', '3'], 'cd': ['4', '5', '6'], 'ef': ['7', '10', '11']}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the string function called startswith(). Here is the code:

```
result = []
for k, v in example_dictionary.items(): 
    for item in keymatch: 
        if k.startswith(item): 
            result.append(v)
```

You might find this useful [tutorial for startswith](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_startswith.htm).